# Select records skipping rows in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I can select some records on database skipping a number o rows in MS Access.
In MySQL is `LIMIT x, y`. Firebird is `FIRST x SKIP y` etc..

No lucky on Google at all =(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how many records you want to skip, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable x
WHERE x.ID NOT IN (SELECT Top 10 id FROM myTable ORDER BY ....)
ORDER BY ...
```

Then you could exclude the records that you don't want.

If you then know the total number of records that you want to return, then you could do the following:

```
SELECT Top 50 *
FROM myTable x
WHERE x.ID NOT IN (SELECT Top 10 id FROM myTable ORDER BY ....)
ORDER BY ...
```