# How to select last set of rows from query in ms access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run two queries one that selects the first 22 rows and one that selects the remaining rows of the query. I am able to select the top 22 rows. But now I need to select the next 22 rows. Basically I have 2 reports in access, one that displays the first 22 rows, and the next would display the next 22 rows.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Does anyone know a function that could send me in the right direction?

Here is my query so far that select the top 22 rows:

```
SELECT TOP 22[UB-04_line_items].client_id, [UB-04_line_items].revenue_code, Revenue_Codes.rev_code_desc, [UB-04_line_items].total_chgs, [UB-04_line_items].cpt_code, [UB-04_line_items].service_units, [UB-04_line_items].service_date, [UB-04_line_items].total_chgs, Sum(IIf(IsNull([reason_code])=False,[disputed_amount],0)) AS [AMT DISPUTED], GetList("Select Distinct reason_code From [Itemized_statements] As T1 Where t1.reason_code <> NULL AND  t1.client_id = " & [Itemized_statements].client_id & " AND T1.revenue_code = " & [Itemized_statements].revenue_code & "","",", ") AS [Err Code]
FROM [UB-04_line_items] INNER JOIN (Itemized_Statements LEFT JOIN Revenue_Codes ON Itemized_Statements.revenue_code = Revenue_Codes.revenue_code) ON [UB-04_line_items].client_id = Itemized_Statements.client_id
GROUP BY [UB-04_line_items].client_id, [UB-04_line_items].revenue_code, Revenue_Codes.rev_code_desc, [UB-04_line_items].cpt_code, [UB-04_line_items].service_units, [UB-04_line_items].service_date, [UB-04_line_items].total_chgs, [UB-04_line_items].total_chgs, Itemized_Statements.client_id, Itemized_Statements.revenue_code
HAVING ((([UB-04_line_items].client_id)=[Itemized_Statements].[client_id]) AND ((Itemized_Statements.client_id)=[forms]![frmClients]![client_ID]) AND ((Itemized_Statements.revenue_code)=[UB-04_line_items].[revenue_code]))
ORDER BY Itemized_Statements.client_id;
```

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455746/select-records-skipping-rows-in-ms-access

Comment: Is client_id distinct in this query or any other field a unique column?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a calculated row number by running count of `client_id` and `revenue_code` (assuming this pair is unique in the aggregate query). Then, use this subquery in `WHERE` clause to condition the needed range. Be sure to remove the `TOP` clause from stored query.

**Top 22**  *(substitute Qry for actual stored query name)*

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Qry sub 
        WHERE sub.client_id < Qry.client_id
            OR (sub.client_id = Qry.client_id
                AND sub.revenue_code <= Qry.revenuce_code)) As RowNo, *
FROM Qry
WHERE (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Qry sub 
        WHERE sub.client_id < Qry.client_id
            OR (sub.client_id = Qry.client_id
                AND sub.revenue_code <= Qry.revenuce_code)) <= 22
```

**Next 22** *(substitute Qry for actual query name)*

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Qry sub 
        WHERE sub.client_id < Qry.client_id
            OR (sub.client_id = Qry.client_id
                AND sub.revenue_code <= Qry.revenuce_code)) As RowNo, *
FROM Qry
WHERE (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Qry sub 
        WHERE sub.client_id < Qry.client_id
            OR (sub.client_id = Qry.client_id
                AND sub.revenue_code <= Qry.revenuce_code)) BETWEEN 23 AND 44
```