# Fill combobox starting from the second record

Tags: vb.net

I Fill My ComboBox1 From Field ( Drivers ) ..with this code all records appears in Combobox1 .. How to make so that the first record does not appear in ComboBox1 .. i want the records to start with the second records in my combobx1 .. the ID numbers are (1-2-3-4-5-6) and so on.

```
    Private Sub Fill_Numeros_Drivers()
    Dim InfoAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim InfoTable As DataSet
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Drivers From Table1"
    InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, Conne)
    InfoTable = New DataSet
    InfoTable.Clear()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable, "Table1")
    For Each rw As DataRow In InfoTable.Tables("Table1").Rows
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(rw(0).ToString())
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Many ways... You can delete the first row, you can use a normal loop starting with the second row, you can use the IEnumerable method Skip(1)

Comment: Please how will my code be with loop starting with the second row ..

Comment: I want to fill ComboBox1 with all records in field from the second record until the last one

Comment: @SABRINE Please note that the database query results *could* come back in any order unless you explicitly use an `ORDER BY`. Also, [Select records skipping rows in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10455746/1115360).

Comment: I tried like this but my ComboBox1 is empty no name appears in my combobox (    Sql_Str = " SELECT DISTINCT Drivers From Table1 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Top 10 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id)"

Comment: @SABRINE I think that should be `SELECT DISTINCT Drivers FROM Table1 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id) ORDER BY Id`. It is "TOP 1" because you want to exclude the first *1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your database objects local so you control their closing and disposing. Using...End Using blocks will do that for you even if there is and error.

I added a field to the query for DriverID. Whatever your Primary Key field is might be appropriate to assure the order of the records. The field in the Order By clause must be in the Select part of the query when DISTINCT is used. This field is downloaded but never used.

The first call to reader.Read reads the first record but nothing is done with it. The second call to reader.Read is now on the second record.

```
Private Sub Fill_Numeros_Drivers()
    Using Conne As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Drivers, DriverID From Table1 Order By DriverID", Conne)
            Conne.Open()
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                reader.Read() 'Reads the first record
                Do While reader.Read
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```